# Unified Buddy List in iChat - how to handle same person on different networks

Tags: macos, facebook, ichat, chat

I have a few people between Facebook/Gchat/AIM that I have IM info for them on more than one account. This could be the case, espc. with multiple Jabber accounts.

With the unified buddy list in 10.7, how to I send an IM to someone through Google chat versus Facebook?

There is a drop down at the top of the IM that says who it is from, but that shows up even if I know the person is on one network and not the other.

**Update:** It seems that sometimes the name will show up twice, but hard to tell which is which. Wondering if there was a better way to do this that I may be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In more than one case now, it looks like multiple copies of the name will show up. You have to either check the buddy picture or other features (for example, video chat doesn't show up for Facebook) to determine which network you are contacting them on.